# Dynamic Database Connection Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, database-connection

I am working on a new application that must connect to several databases. The  databases are dynamically created when a new company is registered in my application i.e each company have there on databases.

My question is how to establish the database connection using laravel,

**If the company admin is login he needs to connect the corresponding db. How is it possible** ???

I know how to establish multiple database connection if the databases are stable, like,

```
'mysql1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
...

'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
...
```

but if the databases are not stable how is it possible ????

If my question is not up to standard, please forgive me

Answer (score 1):

You can add dynamically the database configuration like this.

```
if(NULL === config()->get('database.connections.company')){
        config()->set('database.connections.company', [
            'driver'    => $companyDbDriver,
            'host'      => $companyDbHost,
            'port'      => $companyDbPort,
            'database'  => $companyDbName,
            'username'  => $companyDbUser,
            'password'  => $companyDbPassword,
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false
        ]);
    }
```

in the model; set the connection attribute to `'company'`

```
/**
 * Connection configuration ID.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $connection = 'company';
```

there are complication if you dont load the configuration of the database before calling the models using it, i'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know where your database connections parameters are stored.
Anyway, wherever they are, you should create a new connection on the fly.
Supposing each User has it's own connection ...

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

$user = Users::find($id);
Config::set('database.connections.' . $user->username, array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $user->db_host,
        'database'  => $user->db_name,
        'username'  => $user->db_user,
        'password'  => $user->db_pass,
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
));
// And set the new connection to interested models
$myModel = new MyModel;
$myModel->setConnection($user->username);
$data = $myModel->where(...)->get();
```

Hope this help